# Is latency the time it takes to get the first byte?

Tags: latency

If I request an image from a server, would latency be the time it takes to receive the first byte of the image?

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_%28engineering%29) explains it rather well

> Latency in a packet-switched network is measured either one-way (the time from the source sending a packet to the destination receiving it), or round-trip (the one-way latency from source to destination plus the one-way latency from the destination back to the source). Round-trip latency is more often quoted, because it can be measured from a single point. Note that round trip latency excludes the amount of time that a destination system spends processing the packet.

Answer (score 0):

The round-trip for the request and the first network packet in the response actually.